# Check if second or microsecond were provided in a datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Is there a way to determine for a python datetime object if time attributes were included at the time the object was created? In particular, I would like to know if minutes, seconds or microseconds were provided.

For example, the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime(2020,1,24)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 24, 0, 0)
d.microsecond
# 0

# ideally, if function "has_seconds()" did exist...
if not d.has_seconds():
     d = d.replace(second=59)
```

I am working on a function where I receive a datetime object and I need to fill-in any information that was not provided originally. However, datetime assumes a value 0 for all time attributes that were not provided originally. Unfortunately, 0 is valid for hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds, so I cannot use that to check.

I am using Python 3.7, in case it's of relevance.

Comment: I doubt this information is available. If you are concerned about filling in missing information, you should be creating the object yourself to begin with, rather than accepting a pre-made object.

Comment: I fail to see the logic here: if you have the means to fill the time info correctly you also have the info to check if the object contain the right info. In any case the chance of the original input being exactly `0` for all the relevant fields is quite low, and perhaps you can take the chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't going to be possible with a `datetime.datetime` instance. As you note, the constructor automatically fills in missing values with `0`. Furthermore, there are other ways to create an instance of `datetime.datetime` beyond its constructor. There's no meaningful distinction between instances created by these various methods. If they have the same underlying value, they are equivalent and indistinguishable, by design. In other words, the `datetime` module is designed to actively discourage what you are trying to do.

Without knowing more about your specific use-case and why you need this behavior, it's difficult to suggest an alternative.

However, if you have control over the code that calls your function, your best bet is probably to define and accept your own `datetime.datetime`-like class that offers a similar constructor, but which does not implicitly replace unspecified values with `0`. Callers of your function would have to pass instances of your class instead of `datetime.datetime`. Once you have applied your custom "missing value" logic, you can create a fully-populated `datetime.datetime` object and proceed.